# No image available after turning camera off then turning back on

Tags: java, webcam, capture, webcam-capture

Good day,
I have a problem with my project using sarxos webcam capture. When running the project, camera is working just fine. I have a button to turn on/off the camera, if turned on the numpad is enabled and if off, numpad is disabled and camera will be enabled, but after turning on back the camera, the panel displays "No image available" but it can still capture bar codes, it has just no display. Tried googling some possible way but no luck, also tried repaint() and revalidate() the panel but still not working.
[Camera on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRfnd.png)
[Camera turned back on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uUAU.png)

```
camOrNumpad.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {   
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
   if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
     camOrNumpad.setText("Camera On");
     keyP.clear();
     CamSacnner.webcam.open(); //on camera

     numpad.setEnabled(false);
     numScanImg.setVisible(false);
     numScanIDView.setVisible(false);
     numScanName.setVisible(false);
     camScanViewHide.setVisible(false);
     camScanImg.setVisible(true);
     camScanIDView.setVisible(true);
     camScanName.setVisible(true);


   } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
     camOrNumpad.setText("Camera Off");

     CamSacnner.webcam.close(); //off camera

     camScanView.setEnabled(false);
     numpad.setEnabled(true);
     camScanImg.setVisible(false);
     camScanIDView.setVisible(false);
     camScanName.setVisible(false);
     camScanViewHide.setVisible(true);
     numScanImg.setVisible(true);
     numScanIDView.setVisible(true);
     numScanName.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

});

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already edited my post, providing the jbutton listener